# Does idiomatic (e.g. TBB's thread_enumerable_specific') move assignment call destructor on original object

Tags: c++, move, tbb

let's say I'm working with an idiomatic Cpp library (e.g. Intel's TBB) and have an `in-place` member in some class (e.g. `TsCountersType _ts_counters;`). Such member is automatically initialized by its default constructor (if it exists, otherwise compile error) unless my own `KMeans`'s constructor initialize it explicitely by calling its constructor directly.

Then if I assign a new (created by calling constructor) value to the member field in a normal non-constructor method (e.g. `init`), what exactly is safe to assume?

1. I know that in that case the right side of the assignment is `rvalue` and thus `move assignment` operator will be called.
2. I think it is safe to assume that well behaving idiomatic Cpp code should call the original objects's (e.g. `_ts_counters`) destructor before moving the new object to the memory location. But is such assumption sound?
3. What about default move assignment operator? Does it call destructor on the original object before moving in? Is that even relevant question or is default move assignment operator created by the compiler only if (among other conditions) no explicit destructor is defined?

   4. If that's the case what happens if I have a scenario similar to the TBB one where instead of `TsCountersType` I have simple custom tipe with a single `unique_ptr` and default everything else (constructors, destructors, move assignments, …). When will the `unique_ptr` get out of scope then?
4. Specifically in TBB's case, can I assume it happens given their [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506245): `Supported since C++11. Moves the content of other to *this intact. other is left in an unspecified state, but can be safely destroyed.`

Example code:

```cpp
class KMeans 
{
  private:
    //...
    // thread specific counters
    typedef std::pair<std::vector<point_t>, std::vector<std::size_t>> TSCounterType;
    typedef tbb::enumerable_thread_specific<TSCounterType> TsCountersType;
    TsCountersType _ts_counters;

  public:
    //...
    KMeans() : _tbbInit(tbb::task_scheduler_init::automatic) {}

    virtual void init(std::size_t points, std::size_t k, std::size_t iters)
    {
        // When _ts_counters is replaced by a new object the destructor is automatically called on the original object
        _ts_counters = TsCountersType(std::make_pair(std::vector<point_t>(k), std::vector<std::size_t>(k)));

    }
};
```

Comment: Please, ask only one question per question.

Comment: What do you mean by _moving the new object to the memory location_? Moving objects in memory do not exist in C++.

Comment: While I agree with you both of these questions are highly integrated and asking them separately doesn't make much sense IMO.

Comment: @DanielLangr Well if I understood it correctly from semantics point of view `_ts_counters = TsCountersType(...);` creates a new object `TsCountersType(...)` (as an `rvalue`) and then _moves_ it to `_ts_counters`.

Actual implementation doesn't have to move anything anywhere, of course.

Comment: Here, the move assignment op. of `TsCounterType` is invoked, if it exists (copy assign. op. otherwise). It should, by convention, guarantee that 1) the left-hand side (`_ts_counters`) will have the same _contents_ as the right-hand side before `=`, and 2) the right-hand side will remain in some state (empty, unspecified, etc, possibly not having the same contents as before `=`). There is **no destructor involved** for `_ts_counters`. There is no moving objects in memory involved (again, it does not exist). The actual operation depends on the definition of move assign. op. of `TsCountersType`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
#include<iostream>

struct S
{
    S() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
    S(S const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
    S(S&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}
    S& operator=(S const &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this;}
    S& operator=(S&&) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; return *this;}
    ~S() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl; }
};

struct W
{
    W() : s{} {}
    void init() { s = S{}; }
private:
    S s;
};

int main()
{
    W w{};
    w.init();
}
```

The output this produces (clang and gcc tested):

```
S::S()
S::S()
S &S::operator=(S &&)
S::~S()
S::~S()
```

So, what happens exactly:

- `W`'s constcructor is called, which default initializes `S`
- A temporary `S` is default constructed and immediately moved from into `W::s` member
- Temporary object is now destructed (just before init exits)
- `W::s` is destructed on main exit.

Comment: It seems that with default move constructor the temporal object doesn't get destructed. See: https://onlinegdb.com/S1Si9AudE

Comment: It does, and you can see it in the output. There are 2 objects constructed and two destructed.

Comment: Yep, we figured it out in another question. Thanks!